# Android Grid View Issue (Wrongly Sorting)

Tags: android, sql-server, gridview, layout

i have a project about importing datas from SQL Server and i used grid view layout for listing and sorting whole things but when i try to slide down some problems are occuring.

i have 60 item in my database but it shows 30 also when i slide down its just make it reverse. Here is an example:

Normally:

101 102 103 104
105 106 107 108
109 110 111 112
113 114 115 116
117 118 119 120

When i slide down:

104 103 102 101

105 106 107 108
112 111 110 109

113 114 115 116

120 119 118 117

[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBoCo.png)

Comment: Please provide your code or logic where you are doing sorting

Comment: i just added that part.

Comment: Please copy and paste your code here.